# change the url and display the ajax content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
$(function(){
  $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#Content").fadeOut(800);

    setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){

        $("#Content").fadeIn(900);  
        $('#Content').html(data);

      }});
    }, 900);
    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'

    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
      window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);  
    }

    return false;  
  });

});
```

I want to change content by ajax with change url ,, I use above code but it is make site very slow . How can I make it fast when I click to any page in site ?

Thanks

Comment: In average users don't like waiting for longer than 3 seconds or less for content, unless there are expected long operations. Only making the call 900ms after a user clicked so you can fadeout the page is a third of that. Consider shortening the timeout and fadeout/ins. Any other delay outside this is either time the server takes to get back to you and/or rendering time, depending on the size of the content.

Comment: Maybe load() instead of ajax

Comment: @turson: `load()` is a shorthand `ajax`. Same thing.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, of course, but using `ajax` instead of `load` when we don't send any requests is a bit senseless

Comment: @turson:I'm not sure what you mean by `when we don't send any requests`. `load()` is sending a request to the specified URL just like `$ajax()` does. `load()` is closely similar to the shorthand `$.get()` but they all send requests.

Answer (score 0):

The `fadeIn()/fadeOut()/setTimeout()` delays are slowing things down. Reduce or remove them.

```
$(function(){
  $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){

    //get the link location that was clicked
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#Content").fadeOut(50);

    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){

      $('#Content').html(data);
      $("#Content").fadeIn(25);  

    }});

    //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'

    //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
      window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);  
    }

    return false;  
  });

});
```